# compilation error c++ while adding function in header file

Tags: c++

The question is trivial but not able to resolve the error so asking here.

I am breaking a simple program by writing a function the function in .h and including it later on the main file. 
This is causing compilation error.

I created two files as

```
int remAnagram(string str1, string str2){
    int occ1[SIZEOFALPHA];
    int occ2[SIZEOFALPHA];
    int len1, len2, tot=0;

    len1 = str1.size();
    len2 =  str2.size();
    for(int i =0; i<SIZEOFALPHA; i++){
        occ1[i] = 0;
        occ2[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i =0; i < len1; i++){
        occ1[str1[i] - 'a'] += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < len2; i++){
        occ2[str2[i] - 'a'] += 1;
    }
    for(int i =0; i < SIZEOFALPHA; i++){
        tot += abs(occ1[i]- occ2[i]);
    }

    return tot;
}

#endif // REMANAGRAM_H_INCLUDED
```

and function with main files as

```
#include "remAnagram.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str1, str2;

    cin >> str1 >> str2;
    cout << remAnagram(str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

giving the following error:

remAnagram.h|8|error: 'string' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Drop `using namespace std;` and write out `std::string`.

Comment: Obviously, the compiler doesn't know which `string` you are talking about. Hence either do `using namespace std;` before usage, or better still always do `std::string`

Comment: @Djack Thanks.. but i still didn't get out of which strings compiler is getting ambiguity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refer to `std::string` instead of `string` and get out of the `using namespace std` habit.

That solves the problem in your header file.

You want the signature to look like:

```
int remAnagram(const string& str1, const string& str2)
```

Also avoid using fixed-length C-style arrays if you're dealing with dynamic lists. Your arbitrary length of 26 here might seem adequate now, but if you need to account for other characters like ß or  in the future you'll have to expand on that. A `std::map` might be a better call here.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` should be dropped as well.

Comment: Yeah, this is full of anachronisms that are causing trouble.

Comment: @tadman std::string is solving the problem.. but can u be more specific in this, why shouldn't we use `using namespace std`

Comment: It causes conflict with your own classes and confuses where those things come from. Just use the `std::` prefix to be clear that these are part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the order of `include` statements

**This is a dirty solution and bad style. Do not use it in production code**:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include "remAnagram.h"
```

Comment: @krishnakant, I guess the problem is that your code does not compile. So if you put `#include "remAnagram.h"` after other includes your code should compile

Comment: it is helping but i asked how it is helping in compilation.

Comment: `using namespace std` isn't good in itself, but putting it before `#include` is even worse - you lose control on the scope of using namespace std.

Comment: @Karadur, totally agree. I've put the warning in my answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Get rid of `using namespace std;` and use `std::string` everywhere
2. Put `#include <string>` on the top of remAnagram.h
3. Remove `#include <string>` from your .cpp file

Explanation:
In your snippets, compiler includes remAnagram.h first and compiles it but the type std::string isn't known until you include the type declaration by `#include <string>`.

Also as noted above, `using namespace std;` is a bad habit.